# Running command on windows does not allow quotations

Tags: windows, command-line

when i run a command on windows 10 command line that requires a path as one of its params, it works if the path is NOT inside a quotation, but if a path has a space in it, i need to wrap it inside quotes so that it treats as one single path, but then it complains that the file in that path does not exists.

For example:

```
C:/PROJECTS/desktopfiles/public/libs/cpdf/win64/cpdf.exe C:/Users/john/Documents/cat.pdf C:/Users/john/Documents/my_dog.pdf -o C:/Users/john/Documents/cat_dog_Merged.pdf
```

The above works,

the below doesn't (because there is a space in `my dog.pdf`)

```
C:/PROJECTS/desktopfiles/public/libs/cpdf/win64/cpdf.exe C:/Users/john/Documents/cat.pdf C:/Users/john/Documents/my dog.pdf -o C:/Users/john/Documents/cat_dog_Merged.pdf
```

Comment: It should be passed as `"C:\Users\john\Documents\my dog.pdf"`. Interpreting the quotes for argument parsing is primarily up to cpdf.exe -- not the shell or system -- but the program is completely broken if it doesn't support double quotes. Most use the C runtime's `argv` argument parsing or the system's `CommandLineToArgvW`.

Comment: Also, in general use backslash as the path separator in command lines. Many API functions do not support forward slash as a path separator, e.g. the shell path functions such as `PathCchIsRoot`. Also, many programs do not support forward slash as the path separator because it's reserved for option switches. If you know that a program works with forward slash, that's okay for personal use, but you should switch to using backslash, the platform's native path separator, when seeking help on a forum, just for clarity and to avoid needless questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace spaces with a question mark. The question mark is a wildcard to match "any single character", which would be a space in your case. Like this: `my?dog.pdf`. Just make sure that there is no other file matching this pattern. But the system should give you some error message then (which might or might not point to the root of the problem).

Another solution that comes to my mind is a batch file that renames the files in question automatically (replacing spaces with underscores) and renames them back after the pdf merge.

Comment: In Windows, the shell does not process wildcards in the command line of a program. It's up to the program itself, and very few of them implement this feature. More than likely the program will try to open the literal name "my?dog.pdf", which will fails as an invalid name.

Comment: @ErykSun Yes, this is possible. OP needs to verify, to adapt my answer accordingly. If this is the case, the batch file renaming would be the only viable option imho. But for this more information is needed about the use case/workflow. Maybe there are other solutions...?

Comment: In contrast to your idea, I do think the wildcards in a commandline are processed by the command processor before passing them to the program. I have no proof though, since a `notepad.exe %COMPUTERNAME%.txt` would not reveal what is going on.

Comment: The problem of a program not accepting quoted paths in its command line is serious and needs to be directly resolved, if it's not a simple mistake on the part of Phantom007. In the mean time, as a workaround I would prefer creating symlinks instead of renaming the affected files. Or maybe use the legacy 8.3 short name if the file has one. (Creating 8.3 short names is enabled by default with NTFS on the system volume, but an administrator can disable it.)

Comment: `notepad.exe %COMPUTERNAME%.txt` does not contain wildcard characters. The shell does do a first pass to expand environment variables wrapped by "%". Then, for its own internal commands such as `dir`, the shell does implement wildcard expansion in its second pass parsing. But it does not do this for the command line of an external program. A command line in Windows is limited to 32,766 characters, so expanding a wildcard like "*" in a directory would easily exhaust the available space and would not be reliable. Windows programs have to do their own wildcard expansion.

Comment: Even though your words could be true, I need proof/source to change my mind ;) And as I said, I am aware that the environment variable example does not proof anything.

Comment: The CMD shell, despite being over 30 years old, does not have a detailed spec I can reference. You can run experiments to observe its behavior. Also, see the MSVC docs for [command-line parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019) at program startup, which reference a doc for the optional "wsetargv.obj" code that can be included in order to support wildcard expansion of command-line arguments. If the shell were responsible for this in Windows, there would be no pressing need for the C runtime to provide it as optional support.